# How to add sum grouping in SSRS tablix?

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, sum

I am using SSRS 2008.  Now I am trying to SUM one of the fields, "B", in my tablix.  I am doing a record count of "B" where one of the field values ("A") is not equal to a string expression.
So the pseudocode I want is:

```
select SUM(B) where A <> "test"
```

How do I do this?  Right now it is returning one row for every "B" row instead of just one row.  I also tried adding a Total row, but that row is just returning "1".  My expression of the row where I do the grouping on "B" is "=1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field on your report and give it this expression:

```
=SUM(IIf( A <> "test", Fields!B.Value, CDbl(0)))
```